# Athena Table Timestamp With Time Zone Not Possible?

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to create an athena table with a timestamp column that has time zone information. The create sql looks something like this:

```
        CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `tmp_123` (
`event_datehour_tz` timestamp with time zone
        )
        ROW FORMAT SERDE 
          'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
        STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
          'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
        OUTPUTFORMAT 
          'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
        LOCATION
          's3://...'
        TBLPROPERTIES (
          'Classification'='parquet'
        )
```

When I run this, I get the error:

> line 1:8: mismatched input 'external'. expecting: 'or', 'schema', 'table', 'view' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: b7fa4045-a77e-4151-84d7-1b43db2b68f2; proxy: null)

If I remove the `with time zone` it will create the table. I've tried this and `timestamptz`. Is it not possible to create a table in athena that has a `timestamp with time zone` column?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately [Athena does not support timestamp with time zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-types.html).

What you may do is use the `CAST()` function around that function call, which will change the type from `timestamp with time zone` into `timestamp`.

Or, you can maybe save it as `timestamp` and use [AT TIME STAMP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-supported-time-zones.html) operator as given below:

```
 SELECT event_datehour_tz AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles' AS la_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a complete solution after @AswinRajaram answered that Athena does not support timestampo with timezone. Here is how one can `CAST` the timestamp from a string and use it with timezone.

```
select 
parse_datetime('2022-09-10_00', 'yyyy-MM-dd_H'),
parse_datetime('2022-09-10_00', 'yyyy-MM-dd_H') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin',
at_timezone(CAST(parse_datetime('2022-09-10_00', 'yyyy-MM-dd_HH') AS timestamp), 'Europe/Berlin') AS date_partition_berlin,
CAST(parse_datetime('2022-09-10_00', 'yyyy-MM-dd_HH') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin' AS timestamp) AS date_partition_timestamp;
```

```
2022-09-10 00:00:00.000 UTC
2022-09-10 02:00:00.000 Europe/Berlin // time zone conversion + 2 hours
2022-09-10 02:00:00.000 Europe/Berlin // time zone conversion + 2 hours
2022-09-10 00:00:00.000
```